# Using realm with infinite scrolling table view in swift

Tags: realm, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

Im learning about using NSOperation, NSOperationQueue for my networking calls to deliver a more responsive UI in my apps' table view.

The result of the networking operation get stored into the realm and displayed in the table view.

This is an infinite scroll table view and as the user gets the end, more data is pulled into the app.

I am wondering what is the best design paradigm to use here, and where is the best spot to clear the realm. I don't want to inflate the app with useless data. I just want them to have data if they log back in with no network (airplane mode).

I also would like to know where the best spot to trigger these networking operations is? cellForRowAtIndexPath perhaps? I am not to sure since I usually just use Alamofire and trigger a network request in viewDidLoad. But these are not cancellable calls.

I've gone through the great tutorials on ray wenderlich but other then the playground examples, I am still not getting a real world application tutorial. If anyone knows of a good one on this subject let me know

thanks

Answer (score 1):

This might be tricky to answer since it all depends on your app, the size/type of data it's displaying and how often you want to perform network fetches. In the end, it will be most likely be a compromise between what 'feels good' and how many system resources need to be consumed to make it happen.

In this particular scenario, Realm is being used as a caching mechanism and nothing more, so when to clear it should probably depend on how aggressively you wish to clear it.

If I was building a system like this, I would decide on a set number of the latest items I would always want to have available and save them in Realm. If the user then decided to start scrolling down beyond that limit, more data would be downloaded and appended to the Realm database as they went. Eventually the user will get tired and scroll back to the top (Or they might even just quit the app and restart from the top). At that point, it would be appropriate to trigger an operation to review the size of the Realm cache and remove as many items as necessary to bring it back to the desired size. If they start scrolling down again, then it's appropriate to just re-download that data.

Unlike SQLite, where items are copied into memory, Realm is very good at lazy-loading resources mapped from disk, so it's not necessary to worry about the number of Realm items in memory, more just the size of the Realm file on disk, which again depends on how big the data you're downloading is.

As for when to trigger another network operation to request more data, it's probably best to do it in `tableView(_:willDisplay:forRowAt:)`. Depending on how large the data to download is (and the size of your table cells are), you should play with it until it feels natural when scrolling at a pretty normal speed. As a starting point, I'd recommend starting at maybe a whole screen-worth of table cells before hitting the bottom of the scroll view.

Good luck!